# Conditional Navigation in Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

I am using Caliburn Micro in a windows phone 8 app with a Bindable App Bar. 
When I click a button I want the to check in the event if I am navigating to the same page as the one which is currently displayed.

What would be the code here

```
if((Check with navigation service if you are navigating to the same page) == true)
    return;
else
    NavigationService.UriFor<ViewModel>().Navigate();
```

Comment: Why navigate if you stay in the same page?

Comment: I assume you have some global navigation bar which for some reason allows you to nav to the same place that you are actually visiting currently?

Comment: I am using the bindable app bar that is bound to event defined in a ViewModelBase class so the functionality is shared by all ViewModels implementing that base class. I realized that when the same button is pressed no navigation takes place so i am good on that side.    But the app bar disappears and reappears. I want to stop that from happening

Answer (score 0):

As **Caliburn Micro** navigates via ViewModels, this should work...

```
if (this.GetType() != typeof(CurrentViewModel)) 
  { 
    NavigationService.UriFor<SomeNewViewModel>().Navigate();
  }
```